# Is it fair to say that Hausdorff Distance (HD) focuses on low level details while dice score (DSC) high level

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow, cnn, pytorch

I wonder if its make sense to say that Hausdorff Distance (HD) measures low-level details while dice score (DSC) focuses on high levels.
If you could cite a paper, I would appreciate it.